# Php Version Issue in laravel paypal integration

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am trying to install paypal package and facing this error

This is how my composer.json looks

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "gloudemans/shoppingcart": "^2.5",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
```

[image]

Comment: Update Your PHP

Comment: Your php version is 7.1.1, but it needs php 7.1.3 or greater. Update your php.

Comment: @meysam thanks for your reply but i want to know any other solution except for this if there is any ?

Comment: @AsifNawaz You can use version `1.0` of `netshell/paypal` which requires version `5.4` of php. But it uses version `4` of `illuminate/support` which is not compatible with laravel 5.